# Logging request timeouts on Django + Gunicorn + Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

We have a Django app running Gunicorn with sync workers that's deployed on Heroku. Our request response time shows several requests that hit 30s (and die), which is the default Gunicorn timeout.

What is the best way to log these requests and analyze the timeout? Gunicorn doesn't seem to provide a hook for catching these timeouts, at least not something that's obvious.

Comment: 30 seconds is the HEROKU timeout and you may be seeing what happens when Heroku terminates a connection, separate from any Gunicorn timeout.  I think Gunicorn has its own timeout system; have you tried setting the timeout in Gunicorn to be lower than the Heroku one and seeing if that will show up in logs/metrics better than the ones Heroku kills?

Comment: @AndrewGorcester this is also the gunicorn default http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/18.0/configure.html#timeout though I agree setting it lower than 30s can be a good test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/768/files added a `worker_abort` signal which is what I'm using in this case.

Answer (score 1):

One rather rough way to do it is have a "watchdog" timer that interrupts the process after, say, 25 seconds.  Once you have an idea of which procs are slow, you can refine the data to figure out what's going on.

Example:

```
import signal

def timeout(_signum, _frame):
    print 'TIMEOUT'

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout)
signal.alarm(1)                 # send SIGALRM in 1 second

print 'waiting'
signal.pause()
print 'done'
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not sure it'll be easy to inject this into the WSGI cycle. Whatever solution I choose, must be able to reliably work in production, since that's where I'm getting occasional timeouts. I won't be able to run this on a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to fire off a `Thread` which pokes the main code after a certain amount of elapsed time.  It has several caveats -- be sure to read the ActiveState link.

Here's one implementation by Aaron Swartz from [ActiveState.com](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483752/)

```
import threading
class TimeoutError(Exception): pass

def timelimit(timeout):
    def internal(function):
        def internal2(*args, **kw):
            class Calculator(threading.Thread):
                def __init__(self):
                    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                    self.result = None
                    self.error = None

                def run(self):
                    try:
                        self.result = function(*args, **kw)
                    except:
                        self.error = sys.exc_info()[0]

            c = Calculator()
            c.start()
            c.join(timeout)
            if c.isAlive():
                raise TimeoutError
            if c.error:
                raise c.error
            return c.result
        return internal2
    return internal
```